# How can I remove metadata from an Azure Blob using Azure.Storage v12 SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've created a method that adds metadata to an Azure Blob. I also need to remove metadata and can't find any specific method or documentation to help me.

Is the only way to create a brand new set of metadata and overwrite it using `SetMetadata()` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to "remove" (*reset*) metadata is, like you said, to create a new set of metadata & overwrite existing metadata using [`SetMetaData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.setmetadata?view=azure-dotnet) or [`SetMetaDataAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.setmetadataasync).

Currently, as of .NET v12 SDK, there is no way to reset metadata.

Something like this should work:

```
public static async Task ResetBlobMetadataAsync(BlobContainerClient container)
{
    try
    {
        var newMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        await container.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"HTTP error code {e.Status}: {e.ErrorCode}");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```